# why do I get always a Memory Error after I run dask with big Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am relatively new at Dask using with large DataFrames, so iam not quite sure that this is the best way but I have a few large files to merge them together (each are 30 - 50 million rows) and I always get memory error message with using dask dataframe.

here what I tried in a simplified form:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

##### files opening

```
df1= pd.read_csv(directory / df1, sep=',', blocksize = None )
df1= dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions = 1)

df2= dd.read_csv(directory / df2, sep=',', blocksize = None )
 
df3= dd.read_parquet(directory / df3,  blocksize = None , engine='fastparquet')

df4= dd.read_parquet(directory / df4, blocksize = None , engine='fastparquet')

df5= dd.read_parquet(directory / df5, blocksize = None , engine='fastparquet')

df6= dd.read_parquet(directory / df6, blocksize = None , engine='fastparquet')

df7 = pd.read_excel(directory / df7)
df7= dd.from_pandas(df7, 1)
```

##### Merge them together

```
all_df= df1.merge(df2, on=['store','pmg'], how='inner')
all_df= all_df.merge(df3, on=['store','day', 'tpnb'], how='left')
all_df= all_df.merge(df4[['store', 'tpnb', 'srp', 'nsrp']], on=['tpnb', 'store'], how='left')
all_df= all_df.merge(df5, on=['store', 'tpnb'], how='left')
all_df= all_df.merge(df6[['store', 'day', 'tpnb', 'unit','capacity']], on = ['store', 'day', 'tpnb'], how = 'left')
all_df= all_df.merge(df7, on = ['country', 'tpnb'], how = 'left')
all_df= all_df.fillna(0)
all_df['dep'] = all_df.pmg.str[:3]
```

##### other operations on columns

```
all_df['nsrp'] = all_df['nsrp'].mask((all_df.srp==0)&(all_df.nsrp==0), 1)
all_df['icase'] = all_df['icase'].mask(all_df.icase==0, all_df.capacity)
all_df= all_df.drop(['capacity'], axis=1)
all_df=  all_df.rename(columns={'icase': 'capacity'})
all_df['capacity'] = all_df['capacity'].mask(all_df.capacity < all_df.art_capacity, all_df.art_capacity)
all_df['c_d'] = all_df['unit'] / all_df['capacity']
all_df= all_df.drop(['art_capacity'], axis=1)
all_df= all_df.fillna(0)
all_df['unit_type'] = all_df['unit_type'].mask(all_df.unit_type!='KG', "SNGL")

all_df= all_df.compute()
```

Do you have any idea how can I set it not to run out of memory?

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
```

I ve already tried the code above with setting the n_workers and threads_per_worker parameters as well but getting this "distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker" message after it.

Comment: example: Client(memory_limit = '64GB')

Comment: @GedasMiksenas thx for your comment. In case I set more memory than i have ("32 GB") I got the following error message :  "TypeError: transition_executing_error() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'exception_text' and 'traceback_text'"

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will allow us to help you better :)

Answer (score 1):

Joins are very computationally expensive in a parallel+distributed setting, so you need to take extra care in how you're merging. Here are some options:

- You may consider doing a ["sorted join"](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html#sorted-joins) by [setting the index](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html);
- Joining with 1-partitions Dask DataFrames, or a pandas DataFrames can be well-parallelized, so consider doing that when possible;
- Try persisting some data, see these [best practices];(https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#persist-intelligently)
- If you're still running out of memory, maybe tinker with the partition sizes -- the "Worker Memory" plot in the Dask Dashboard is super useful here (orange/grey bars mean you're running out of memory).

Also, you might find these interesting:

- [DataFrame Joins documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html)
- [How to Merge Dask DataFrames](https://coiled.io/blog/dask-dataframe-merge-join/)